# How to use Jquery Datatable with AngularJs to export table

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datatables, export-to-pdf

I am working on angular website where I need to export table's data to pdf.

I want to use jQuery datatables for it as it alse add some more features like paging,searching and sorting, but getting this error "**Error: [$injector:unpr]**" on browser's console, even I am not sure using **ng-table** will make it to datatable or not.

I have also tried using jquery plugin [pdfmake](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.22/pdfmake.min.js) but it only make signle page pdf and failed if table have larger data.
Please help and TIA.

**Html :-**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-table/1.0.0/ng-table.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-table/1.0.0/ng-table.min.js"></script>

            <table id="myYealyGrid" ng-class="myYealyGridClass" class="table table-responsive gridtable" ng-table="yearly_Table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Customer Name</th>
                        <th>Year</th>
                        <th>Total Amount($)</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                    <tr ng-show="YearlyReport.length !=0" ng-repeat="reportrow in YearlyReport" ng-init="setTotal(reportrow)">
                        <td>{{reportrow.CustomerName}}</td>
                        <td>{{reportrow.Month}}</td>
                        <td>{{reportrow.TotalAmount}}</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr ng-show="YearlyReport.length ==0">
                        <td><small class="nodata">No data found.</small></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr ng-show="YearlyReport.length !=0" class="bg-warning">
                        <td class="td-font-bold-custm">Total</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td class="td-font-bold-custm">{{gridTotalAmount | number:2}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
```

**AngularJs:-**

```
var appKitchenOrderReport = angular.module("myKitchenOrderReportApp",  ['ngTable']);

appKitchenOrderReport.controller("myKitchenOrderReportCntrl", function ($scope, $window, $timeout, myKitchenOrderReportService, ngTableParams) {

  var getData = myKitchenOrderReportService.SearchData($scope.CustomerName, $scope.Year);
        getData.then(function (kitchenreportdata) {

 var yearlyGridData = kitchenreportdata.data.OrderYearlyReport;
                $scope.yearly_Table = new ngTableParams({
                    page: 1,
                    count: 10
                }, {
                    total: $scope.yearlyGridData.length,
                    getData: function ($defer, params) {
                        $scope.YearlyReport = $scope.yearlyGridData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count());
                        $defer.resolve($scope.YearlyReport);
                    }
                });
 }, function () {
            alert('Error in getting data');
        });

});


appKitchenOrderReport.service("myKitchenOrderReportService", function ($http) {

    this.getKitchenOrderReportData = function () {        
        var response = '';  
        return $http.get("GetOrderReport");    };

    this.SearchData = function (CustomerName, Year)
    {          
        var GetParams = new Object();        
        GetParams.CustomerName = CustomerName;          
        GetParams.Year = Year  

        var response = $http({
            method: "post",
            url: "GetOrderReport",
            data: '{model: ' + JSON.stringify(GetParams) + '}',        
        });
        return response;
    }
});
```

Comment: Take a look at **http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/archives/#!/welcome**

Answer (score 0):

you can Use  $('#myYealyGrid').DataTable(); to initialize your datatable .

But Use just befor , when you Put data into the HTML table .

It will automatically initialize your Datatable.

Try it and let me know is it working or not .

Comment: $('#myYealyGrid').DataTable();  var yearlyGridData = kitchenreportdata.data.OrderYearlyReport;

Comment: what is the error and where you have used i mean after rendering the table or before

Comment: before rendering data, it creates datatable, no error but sorting, paging not working...

Comment: ya i got it , check the columns properly ,  the numbers of th should match the number of td tag..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161801/discussion-between-dotnet-and-sunil-chaudhary).